# I can't draw my current Position on a MapBox Sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, mapbox

I implementing offline and online `maps` by using `MapBox Sdk`. I try to draw a blue translucent circle to show my actual `GPS` Position on `MapBox Sdk` Map but it shows no circle.And couldn't find the current location.Thanks in Advance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"control-room-0.2.0" ofType:@"mbtiles"];

    self.mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,70, 320, 500) andTilesource:offlineSource];
    [self.mapView removeAllAnnotations];
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;

    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = NO;

        [ self.mapView setDelegate:self];
        [self.view addSubview: self.mapView];
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;



    // default zoom
     self.mapView.zoom = 4;
    // hard code minimal zoom. Try to run in without it to see what happens.
     self.mapView.minZoom = 1;

     self.mapView.maxZoom = 8;

    self.mapView.tileSourcesMinZoom=5.0;
    self.mapView.tileSourcesMaxZoom=16.0;

    // hide MapBox logo
     self.mapView.showLogoBug = NO;
    // hide bottom right "i" icon
    [self.mapView setHideAttribution:YES];

     self.mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
     self.mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

    [ self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:RMUserTrackingModeFollow animated:true];

}
```

Comment: Your code fragments are composed of incomplete blocks (closing braces '}' with no opening braces '{'  Make sure you've got all the relevant code posted, and apply standard formatting to it so it's legible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this method:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Also if you want to change the icon of that RMAnnotaiton you can use:

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    RMMarker *marker;

    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation) {
        marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-con-halo.png"]];
    }
    return marker;
}
```